# calendar scheduler in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, calendar, schedule

hey so i'm very new to C and i'm having problems in my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define ENTER 13
#define BCKSPC 8
#define MAX_TASKS 100

#define CREATE_ACCOUNT 2
#define SIGN_IN 1
#define CHANGE_PASSWORD 3
#define EXIT 4

struct user {
    char username[100];
    char password[100];
};

struct task {
    char name[100];
    char notes[100];
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

void displayTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int numTasks, int selectedDate, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear);
void editTask(struct task *task, struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks);
void deleteTask(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks, int selectedDate, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear);
void saveTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int numTasks);
void signIn(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks);
void loadTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks);
void setConsoleColor(int color);
void clearConsoleScreen();
void clearInputBuffer();
void takeInput(char ch[100]);
int getch();
void takePassword(char *str);
void displayMenu();
int getMenuChoice();
int passwordStrength(const char *password);
const char *getMonthName(int month);
void displayCalendar(int month, int year, struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int numTasks, int selectedDay, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear);
void createAccount();
void changePassword();


void setConsoleColor(int color) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), color);
}

void clearConsoleScreen() {
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    DWORD written;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ' ', 100 * 100, coord, &written);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

void clearInputBuffer() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){

    }
}

void takeInput(char ch[100]) {
    fgets(ch, 100, stdin);
    size_t len = strlen(ch);
    
    if (len > 0 && ch[len - 1] == '\n') {
        ch[len - 1] = '\0';
    } else {
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    }
}

int getch() {
    int ch = _getch();
    if (ch == 0 || ch == 0xE0) {
        _getch(); 
    }
    return ch;
}

void takePassword(char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    str[0] = '\0';
    do {
        int ch = getch();
        if (ch == ENTER) {
            str[i] = '\0';
            break;
        } else if (ch == BCKSPC) {
            if (i > 0) {
                i--;
                printf("\b \b");
            }
        } else if (ch == 0 || ch == 0xE0) {
            getch();
        } else {
            str[i] = (char)ch;
            printf("*");
            i++;
        }
    } while (1);

    fflush(stdin);
}

void displayMenu() {
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t------Hello, Welcome to your personalized Schedule App!------\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("Input 1 to Sign In\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("Input 2 to Create Account\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("Input 3 to Change Password\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("Input 4 to Exit\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);
}

int getMenuChoice() {
    int choice;

    while (1) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("Enter your choice (1-4): ");
        setConsoleColor(15);

        if (scanf("%d", &choice) == 1 && choice >= 1 && choice <= 4) {
            clearInputBuffer();
            return choice;
        } else {
            clearInputBuffer();
            setConsoleColor(14);
            printf("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.\n");
            setConsoleColor(15);
        }
    }
}

int passwordStrength(const char *password);

void createAccount() {
    struct user user = {0};
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("Enter your username: ");
    setConsoleColor(15);
    takeInput(user.username);
    
    do {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("Enter your password: ");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        takePassword(user.password);

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nConfirm your password: ");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        char confirmPassword[100];
        takePassword(confirmPassword);

        if (strcmp(user.password, confirmPassword) != 0) {
            setConsoleColor(14);
            printf("\nPasswords do not match. Please try again.\n");
            setConsoleColor(15);
        }else if (!passwordStrength(user.password)){
            setConsoleColor(14);
            printf("\nPassword is too weak. Choose a stronger password\n");
             setConsoleColor(15);
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while (1);

    FILE *fp = fopen("Users.dat", "ab+");
    if (fp == NULL){
        perror("Error in opening file");
        return;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

    int writeResult = fwrite(&user, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    if (writeResult != 0){
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nRegistration successful, Your username is %s\n", user.username);
        setConsoleColor(15);
    }else{
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nSomething went wrong");
        setConsoleColor(15);
    }
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("\nPress Enter to continue...");
    setConsoleColor(15);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    system("cls"); 
}

int passwordStrength(const char *password){
    int length = strlen(password);
    int hasLetter = 0;
    int hasDigit = 0;

    for (int i=0;i < length; i++){
        if(isalpha(password[i])){
            hasLetter = 1;
        } else if (isdigit(password[i])){
            hasDigit = 1;
        }
    }

    if (length >= 6  && (hasLetter || hasDigit )){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
const char *getMonthName(int month) {
    setConsoleColor(14);
    static const char *monthNames[] = {"", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    setConsoleColor(15);
    return monthNames[month];
}
void displayCalendar(int month, int year, struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int numTasks, int selectedDay, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear) {
    system("cls");
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t  \x1b[33m%s %d\x1b[0m\n", getMonthName(month), year);
    setConsoleColor(15);

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf(" +-------------------------------+\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf(" Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf(" +-------------------------------+\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);

    struct tm firstDay = {0};
    firstDay.tm_year = year - 1900;
    firstDay.tm_mon = month - 1;
    firstDay.tm_mday = 1;
    mktime(&firstDay);

    int dayOfWeek = firstDay.tm_wday;

    int daysInMonth;
    if (month == 2) {
        if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
            daysInMonth = 29;
        else
            daysInMonth = 28;
    } else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
        daysInMonth = 30;
    } else {
        daysInMonth = 31;
    }

    int day = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (i == 0 && j < dayOfWeek) {
                printf("     ");
            } else if (day <= daysInMonth) {
                int taskFound = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < numTasks; k++) {
                    if (tasks[k].day == day && tasks[k].month == month) {
                        taskFound = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                int isSelected = (selectedDay == day && selectedMonth == month && selectedYear == year);

                if (isSelected) {
                    printf("\x1b[32m");  
                } else if (taskFound) {
                    printf("\x1b[31m");  
                }

                printf(" %3d ", day);

                if (isSelected || taskFound) {
                    printf("\x1b[0m"); 
                }

                day++;
            }

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf(" +-------------------------------+\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("\nSelect the date to see your tasks (enter 0 to go back): ");
    setConsoleColor(15);

    int selectedDate;
    scanf("%d", &selectedDate);

    int goBack = 0;

    if (selectedDate == 0) {
        goBack = 1;
    } else {
        system("cls");
        displayTasks(tasks, numTasks, selectedDate, month, year);
    }

     if (goBack) {
        return;
    }
    displayTasks(tasks, numTasks, selectedDate, month, year);
}

void displayTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int numTasks, int selectedDate, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear) {
    int goBack = 0;  

    do {
        system("cls");
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t-----Your Tasks and Notes-----\n");
        setConsoleColor(15);

        if (selectedDate != 0 && selectedMonth != 0) {
            printf("\x1b[33m");
            printf("Date: %d %s %d\n", selectedDate, getMonthName(selectedMonth), selectedYear); 
            printf("\x1b[0m");
        }

        int tasksFound = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++) {
            if (tasks[i].day == selectedDate && tasks[i].month == selectedMonth && tasks[i].year == selectedYear) {
                tasksFound = 1;

                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("----------------------------------\n");
                setConsoleColor(15);

                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("Task: %s\n", tasks[i].name);
                setConsoleColor(15);

                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("Notes: %s\n", tasks[i].notes);
                setConsoleColor(15);

                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("----------------------------------\n");
                setConsoleColor(15);

                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("Options:\n");
                printf("1. Edit Task\n");
                printf("2. Delete Task\n");
                printf("3. Go back\n");
                setConsoleColor(15);

                int option;
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("Enter your choice: ");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                scanf("%d", &option);
                while (getchar() != '\n');

                switch (option) {
                    case 1:
                        editTask(&tasks[i], tasks, &numTasks);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        deleteTask(tasks, &numTasks, tasks[i].day, tasks[i].month, tasks[i].year);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        goBack = 1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        setConsoleColor(14);
                        printf("Invalid option. Press Enter to continue..\n");
                        setConsoleColor(15);
                        getch();
                }
                if (goBack){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!tasksFound) {
            setConsoleColor(14);
            printf("\x1b[31mNo tasks found for %d %s %d\x1b[0m \n", selectedDate, getMonthName(selectedMonth), selectedYear);
            setConsoleColor(15);
            setConsoleColor(14);
            printf("\nPress Enter to continue...");
            setConsoleColor(15);
            int enterKey;
            while ((enterKey = getchar()) != '\n' && enterKey != EOF);
            goBack = 1;
        } else {
            setConsoleColor(14);
            printf("\nPress Enter to go back...");
            setConsoleColor(15);
            int enterKey;
            while ((enterKey = getchar()) != '\n' && enterKey != EOF);
        }
    }while (goBack == 0);
}

void editTask(struct task *task, struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks){
    if (*numTasks == 0) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nNo tasks available to edit.");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        return;
    }

    int taskIndex;
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("\nEnter the index of the task to edit (1-%d): ", numTasks);
    setConsoleColor(15);
    scanf("%d", &taskIndex);

    if (taskIndex < 1 || taskIndex > *numTasks) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nInvalid index. Press Enter to go back...");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        return;
    }

    taskIndex--;

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("\nEditing Task:\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);
    printf("Task Name: %s\n", tasks[taskIndex].name);
    printf("Notes: %s\n", tasks[taskIndex].notes);
    printf("Date: %d %s %d\n", tasks[taskIndex].day, getMonthName(tasks[taskIndex].month), tasks[taskIndex].year);
    
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("\nDo you want to edit this task? (1: Yes, 0: No): ");
    setConsoleColor(15);
    int confirmation;
    scanf("%d", &confirmation);

    if (confirmation) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nEnter new task: ");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        takeInput(tasks[taskIndex].name);

        while (getchar() != '\n');

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("Enter new notes: ");
        setConsoleColor(15);
       takeInput(tasks[taskIndex].notes);

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("Enter new day (1-31): ");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        scanf("%d", &tasks[taskIndex].day);
         while(tasks[taskIndex].day < 1 || tasks[taskIndex].day > 31) {
            printf("Invalid day. Please enter a day between 1 and 31: ");
            scanf("%d", &tasks[taskIndex].day);
        }

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("Enter new month (1-12): ");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        scanf("%d", &tasks[taskIndex].month);
         while(tasks[taskIndex].month < 1 || tasks[taskIndex].month > 12) {
            printf("Invalid month. Please enter a month between 1 and 12: ");
            scanf("%d", &tasks[taskIndex].month);
        }

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("Enter new year: ");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        scanf("%d", &tasks[taskIndex].year);
         while(tasks[taskIndex].year < 0) {
            printf("Invalid year. Please enter a positive year: ");
            scanf("%d", &tasks[taskIndex].year);
        }

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nTask edited successfully!");
        setConsoleColor(15);
    } else {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nEdit cancelled.");
        setConsoleColor(15);
    }
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}

void deleteTask(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks, int selectedDate, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear) {
    if (*numTasks == 0) {
        printf("\nNo tasks to delete.\n");
    } else {
        int taskIndex = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < *numTasks; i++) {
            if (tasks[i].day == selectedDate && tasks[i].month == selectedMonth && tasks[i].year == selectedYear) {
                taskIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (taskIndex != -1) {
            for (int i = taskIndex; i < *numTasks - 1; i++) {
                tasks[i] = tasks[i + 1];
            }

            (*numTasks)--;

            printf("\nTask deleted successfully!\n");
        } else {
            printf("\nNo task found on the selected date.\n");
        }
    }

    saveTasks(tasks, *numTasks);
    printf("Press Enter to go back...");

    while (getchar() != '\n');
}

void changePassword() {
    struct user user;
    int userFound = 0;
    char username[100], pword[100];

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("Enter your username: ");
    setConsoleColor(15);
    takeInput(username);
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("Enter your current password: ");
    setConsoleColor(15);
    takePassword(pword);

    FILE *fp = fopen("Users.dat", "r+b");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return;
    }

    while (fread(&user, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp) == 1){
        if (strcmp(user.username, username) == 0 && strcmp(user.password, pword) == 0) {
            userFound = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!userFound) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\n\nUser is not registered or incorrect password!");
        setConsoleColor(15);

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nPress Enter to continue...");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
    } else {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nEnter your new password: ");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        takePassword(user.password);

        size_t len = strlen(user.password);
        if (len > 0 && user.password[len - 1] == '\n') {
            user.password[len - 1] = '\0';
        }

        fseek(fp, -sizeof(struct user), SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(&user, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nPassword changed successfully!");
        setConsoleColor(15);

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nPress Enter to continue...");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        
    }
    fclose(fp);
    system("cls"); 
}

void saveTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int numTasks) {
    FILE *file = fopen("tasks.dat", "wb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file!");
        return;
    }
    fwrite(tasks, sizeof(struct task), numTasks, file);
    fclose(file);
}
void signIn(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks) {
    struct user user = {0};
    int userFound = 0;
    char username[100], pword[100];
    int taskIndex = 0;

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("Enter your username : ");
    setConsoleColor(15);
    takeInput(username);

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("Enter your password : ");
    setConsoleColor(15);
    takePassword(pword);

    FILE *fp = fopen("Users.dat", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening Users.dat");
        return;
    }

    while (fread(&user, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(user.username, username) == 0 && strcmp(user.password, pword) == 0) {
            userFound = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    if (!userFound) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\n\nUser is not registered or incorrect password!");
        setConsoleColor(15);

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nPress Enter to continue...");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        system("cls");
        return;
    }

    int menuChoice;

    do {
        clearConsoleScreen();

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t-----What do you want to do today?-----");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\n1. See your schedule and calendar");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\n2. Add your task and notes");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\n3. Log out");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        scanf("%d", &menuChoice);
        while (getchar() != '\n');

        switch (menuChoice) {
            case 1:{
                int targetMonth, targetYear;
                do{
                    setConsoleColor(14);
                    printf("Enter the month (1-12): ");
                    setConsoleColor(15);
                    if (scanf("%d", &targetMonth) != 1 || targetMonth < 1 || targetMonth > 12) {
                        setConsoleColor(14);
                        printf("Invalid month. Press Enter to go back.\n");
                        setConsoleColor(15);
                        while (getchar() != '\n');
                        getchar();
                    }
                }while (targetMonth < 1 || targetMonth > 12);

                do {
                    setConsoleColor(14);
                    printf("Enter the year (2023-2033): ");
                    setConsoleColor(15);
                    if (scanf("%d", &targetYear) != 1 || targetYear < 2023 || targetYear > 2033) {
                        setConsoleColor(14);
                        printf("Invalid year. Press Enter to go back...\n");
                        setConsoleColor(15);
                        while (getchar() != '\n');
                        getchar();
                    }
                }while (targetYear < 2023 || targetYear > 2033);

                while(getchar() != '\n');

                displayCalendar(targetMonth, targetYear, tasks, *numTasks, 0, 0, 0);

                displayTasks(tasks, *numTasks, tasks[taskIndex].day, tasks[taskIndex].month, tasks[taskIndex].year);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("\nEnter task name: ");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                takeInput(tasks[*numTasks].name);
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("Enter the notes: ");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                takeInput(tasks[*numTasks].notes);
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("Enter the day (1-31): ");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                scanf("%d", &tasks[*numTasks].day);
                if (tasks[*numTasks].day < 1 || tasks[*numTasks].day > 31) {
                    setConsoleColor(14);
                    printf("Invalid day\n");
                    setConsoleColor(15);
                    break;
                }
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("Enter month (1-12): ");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                scanf("%d", &tasks[*numTasks].month);
                if (tasks[*numTasks].month < 1 || tasks[*numTasks].month > 12) {
                    setConsoleColor(14);
                    printf("Invalid month\n");
                    setConsoleColor(15);
                    break;
                }
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("Enter the year (2023-2033): ");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                scanf("%d", &tasks[*numTasks].year);
                if (tasks[*numTasks].year < 2023 || tasks[*numTasks].year > 2033){
                    setConsoleColor(14);
                    printf("Invalid year\n");
                    setConsoleColor(15);
                    break;
                }

                (*numTasks)++;
                saveTasks(tasks, *numTasks);

                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("\nTask added successfully!");
                setConsoleColor(15);

                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("\nPress Enter to continue...");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                getch();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
                printf("\nLogging out...");
                printf("\nPress Enter to continue..");
                while (getchar() != '\n');
                clearConsoleScreen();
                break;
            default:
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("\nInvalid choice.");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("\nPress Enter to go back...");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                while (getchar() != '\n');
        }
    } while (menuChoice != 3);
}

void loadTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks) {
    FILE *file = fopen("tasks.dat", "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        *numTasks = 0;
        return;
    }
    *numTasks = fread(tasks, sizeof(struct task), MAX_TASKS, file);
    fclose(file);
}
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int choice;
    struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS];
    int numTasks = 0;
    int targetDay, targetMonth, targetYear;
    loadTasks(tasks, &numTasks);

     do {
            displayMenu();
            choice = getMenuChoice();

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                signIn(tasks, &numTasks);
                break;
                case 2:
                createAccount();
                break;
                case 3:
                changePassword();
                break;
                case 4:
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("Exiting the application. Goodbye!\n");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                break;
                default:
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("Invalid choice. Please enter a number between 1 and 4.\n");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                clearInputBuffer();
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("Press Enter to go back...");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                while (getchar() != '\n');
                break;
            }
        }

     while (choice != 4);

    if (choice == 1) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nEnter the day of the month: ");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        while(1){
            if( scanf("%d", &targetDay) == 1){
                break;
            }else{
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("\nPlease enter a valid number for the day: ");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                while (getchar() != '\n'); 
            }
        }
        targetMonth = 1;  
        targetYear = 2023;  
        displayCalendar(targetMonth, targetYear, tasks, numTasks, 0, 0, 0);
        displayTasks(tasks, numTasks, targetDay, targetMonth, targetYear);
    }

    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);

    return 0;
}
```

here are the issues:

1. when i added a task in the day, month, and year that i chose (example: 5th january 2023)
   the mark of the task in the calendar is still the same mark when i chose the same month but different year (example: 5th january 2024)
2. having problems with an option in the displayCalendar, when i choose 0 it doesn't take me back to the app menu rather it just takes me to the task and notes menu
3. also have a display error in the edit task (Enter the index of the task to edit (1-6400548): )
4. everytime i delete a task it's still in the edit task
5. everytime i change an account the task, notes, and others are still the same as the account i used to add stuff

help me fix this please and if there are other issues help me fix and understand what's  goin on. Thank you so mcuh

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: so sorry for my lack of exploring, thank you for telling me

Comment: You need to code unit tests for each of your functions.  ( "a function that is not unit tested does not work as intended" )  When a unit test fails, run it under the debugger, stepping through each line to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Dumping 874 lines of code for a minimal reproducible example is not acceptable on this site.

Here are some issues that you should fix:

- `while (getchar() != '\n');` is an infinite loop at the end of file. Use `clearInputBuffer()` instead.  There are multiple occurrences of this problem.
- `takeInput()` should test and report `fgets()` failure to read input (eg: at end of file). It has undefined behavior in this case.
- `passwordStrength()` is rather weak: it accepts 6 character passwords with at least a letter or a digit.
- there is a typo in `getMonthName()`: you wrote `Setconsolecolor` instead of `setConsoleColor`. The program should not compile at all.
- same problem in `dispayCalendar()` with a different typo: `SetConsoleColor` instead of `setConsoleColor`.
- in `editTask`, you should dereference the pointer in `printf("\nEnter the index of the task to edit (1-%d): ", numTasks);` and use `*numTasks` instead. Alternatively, you could pass the number of tasks instead of a pointer to it.
- in `signIn()`, when selecting `1` there is an extra call to `displayTasks` after `displayCalendar` that causes a segmentation fault because it uses the data from uninitialized task `tasks[taskIndex]`. When no tasks have been entered, this data is invalid and `displayTasks` seems to be missing validity tests on its arguments, and it calls `getMonthName()` which returns `monthNames[month]` without testing if `month` is in the range 0 to 12 inclusive. This is causing the segmentation fault.
- in many places, you access `tasks[*numTasks]` which is beyond the end of the valid entries, and you try and correct this problem by decrementing `numTasks` temporarily.  This approach is risky and confusing.  You should instead test if `*numTasks` is `0` and no refer to any task and use a variable `lastTask = *numTasks - 1` to access the last task. Using a pointer would also make the code more readable.

I modified your code to implement some of these ideas and other ones too:

- added entry functions to factorize input code
- added end of file detection
- added portability to linux and macOS

I hope you enjoy studying this code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#else
#define _getch()  getchar()
typedef struct COORD { int x, y; } COORD;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
#define SetConsoleCursorPosition(handle, coord)  ((void)(coord.x))
#define FillConsoleOutputCharacter(handle, a, b, c, d)  (*(d) = (c).x * (c).y)
#define SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, a)
#endif

#define ENTER 13
#define BCKSPC 8
#define MAX_TASKS 100

struct user {
    char username[100];
    char password[100];
};

struct task {
    char name[100];
    char notes[100];
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

void setConsoleColor(int color);
void clearConsoleScreen(void);
int getch(void);
int clearInputBuffer(void);
int pressEnter(void);
int getInput(const char *prompt, char ch[100], size_t size);
int getPassword(const char *prompt, char *str, size_t size);
int passwordStrength(const char *password);
void displayTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int numTasks,
                  int selectedDate, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear);
int editTask(struct task *task, struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks);
int deleteTask(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks,
                int selectedDate, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear);
int saveTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int numTasks);
void signIn(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks);
int loadTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks);
void displayMenu(void);
const char *getMonthName(int month);
void displayCalendar(int month, int year, struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int numTasks,
                     int selectedDay, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear);
int createAccount(void);
int changePassword(void);

/*---------------- implementation ----------------*/

void setConsoleColor(int color) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), color);
}

void clearConsoleScreen(void) {
    COORD coord = { 0, 0 };
    DWORD written;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ' ', 100 * 100, coord, &written);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

int clearInputBuffer(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        continue;
    return c == '\n';
}

int pressEnter(void) {
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("\nPress Enter to continue...");
    setConsoleColor(15);
    return clearInputBuffer();
}

int getInput(const char *prompt, char *str, size_t size) {
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    setConsoleColor(15);
    if (!fgets(str, size, stdin)) {
        printf("EOF");
        return 0;
    }
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (len > 0 && str[len - 1] == '\n') {
        str[--len] = '\0';
    } else {
        clearInputBuffer();
    }
    return 1;
}

int getch(void) {
    int ch = _getch();
    if (ch == 0 || ch == 0xE0) {
        _getch();
    }
    return ch;
}

int getPassword(const char *prompt, char *str, size_t size) {
    size_t i = 0;
    int ch;

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    setConsoleColor(15);

    for (;;) {
        ch = getch();
        if (ch == EOF) {
            printf("EOF");
            break;
        }
        if (ch == ENTER || ch == '\n')
            break;
        if (ch == BCKSPC) {
            if (i > 0) {
                i--;
                printf("\b \b");
            }
        } else {
            if (i + 1 < size) {
                str[i] = (char)ch;
                printf("*");
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    printf("\n");
    if (ch == EOF && i == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

void displayMenu(void) {
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t------Hello, Welcome to your personalized Schedule App!------\n");
    printf("Input 1 to Sign In\n");
    printf("Input 2 to Create Account\n");
    printf("Input 3 to Change Password\n");
    printf("Input 4 to Exit\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);
}

int getInteger(const char *prompt, const char *name, int min, int max, int *dest) {
    for (;;) {
        int res, input;

        setConsoleColor(14);
        if (strchr(prompt, '('))
            printf("%s: ", prompt);
        else
            printf("%s (%d-%d): ", prompt, min, max);
        setConsoleColor(15);

        res = scanf("%d", &input);
        clearInputBuffer();
        if (res == 1 && input >= min && input <= max) {
            *dest = input;
            return 1;
        } else
        if (res == EOF) {
            printf("EOF\n");
            return 0;
        } else {
            setConsoleColor(14);
            printf("Invalid %s. Please enter a number between %d and %d.\n", name, min, max);
            setConsoleColor(15);
        }
    }
}

int createAccount(void) {
    struct user user = { 0 };

    if (!getInput("Enter your username", user.username, sizeof(user.username)))
        return 0;

    for (;;) {
        if (!getPassword("Enter your password", user.password, sizeof user.password))
            return 0;

        char confirmPassword[100];

        if (!getPassword("Confirm your password", confirmPassword, sizeof confirmPassword))
            return 0;

        if (strcmp(user.password, confirmPassword) != 0) {
            setConsoleColor(14);
            printf("\nPasswords do not match. Please try again.\n");
            setConsoleColor(15);
        } else
        if (!passwordStrength(user.password)) {
            setConsoleColor(14);
            printf("\nPassword is too weak. Choose a stronger password\n");
            setConsoleColor(15);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen("Users.dat", "ab+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error in opening file");
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

    int writeResult = fwrite(&user, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    if (writeResult != 0) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nRegistration successful, Your username is %s\n", user.username);
        setConsoleColor(15);
    } else {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nSomething went wrong\n");
        setConsoleColor(15);
    }
    pressEnter();
    clearConsoleScreen();
    return writeResult;
}

int passwordStrength(const char *password) {
    int length = strlen(password);
    int hasLetter = 0;
    int hasDigit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)password[i])) {
            hasLetter = 1;
        } else
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)password[i])) {
            hasDigit = 1;
        }
    }
    if (length >= 6 && hasLetter && hasDigit) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

const char *getMonthName(int month) {
    static const char * const monthNames[] = {
        "", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    };
    if (month < 0 || month > 12)
        return "???";
    else
        return monthNames[month];
}

void displayCalendar(int month, int year, struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS],
                     int numTasks, int selectedDay, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear)
{
    clearConsoleScreen();
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t  \x1b[33m%s %d\x1b[0m\n", getMonthName(month), year);
    printf(" +-------------------------------+\n");
    printf(" Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");
    printf(" +-------------------------------+\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);

    struct tm firstDay = { 0 };
    firstDay.tm_year = year - 1900;
    firstDay.tm_mon = month - 1;
    firstDay.tm_mday = 1;
    mktime(&firstDay);

    int dayOfWeek = firstDay.tm_wday;
    int daysInMonth;
    if (month == 2) {
        if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
            daysInMonth = 29;
        else
            daysInMonth = 28;
    } else
    if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
        daysInMonth = 30;
    } else {
        daysInMonth = 31;
    }

    int day = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (i == 0 && j < dayOfWeek) {
                printf("     ");
            } else if (day <= daysInMonth) {
                int taskFound = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < numTasks; k++) {
                    if (tasks[k].day == day && tasks[k].month == month) {
                        taskFound = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                int isSelected = (selectedDay == day && selectedMonth == month && selectedYear == year);
                if (isSelected) {
                    printf("\x1b[32m");
                } else
                if (taskFound) {
                    printf("\x1b[31m");
                }
                printf(" %3d ", day);

                if (isSelected || taskFound) {
                    printf("\x1b[0m");
                }
                day++;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf(" +-------------------------------+\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);

    int selectedDate = 0;
    if (!getInteger("Select the day to see your tasks (enter 0 to go back)", "day",
                    0, daysInMonth, &selectedDate))
        return;

    if (selectedDate == 0)
        return;

    clearConsoleScreen();
    displayTasks(tasks, numTasks, selectedDate, month, year);
}

void displayTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int numTasks,
                  int selectedDate, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear)
{
    int goBack = 0;

    while (!goBack) {
        clearConsoleScreen();
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t-----Your Tasks and Notes-----\n");
        setConsoleColor(15);

        if (selectedDate != 0 && selectedMonth != 0) {
            printf("\x1b[33m");
            printf("Date: %d %s %d\n", selectedDate, getMonthName(selectedMonth), selectedYear);
            printf("\x1b[0m");
        }

        int tasksFound = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; i++) {
            if (tasks[i].day == selectedDate && tasks[i].month == selectedMonth && tasks[i].year == selectedYear) {
                tasksFound = 1;

                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("----------------------------------\n");
                printf("Task: %s\n", tasks[i].name);
                printf("Notes: %s\n", tasks[i].notes);
                printf("----------------------------------\n");
                printf("Options:\n");
                printf("1. Edit Task\n");
                printf("2. Delete Task\n");
                printf("3. Next task\n");
                printf("4. Go back\n");
                setConsoleColor(15);

                int option = 4;
                if (!getInteger("Enter your choice", "choice", 1, 4, &option))
                    return;

                if (option == 1) {
                    editTask(&tasks[i], tasks, &numTasks);
                } else
                if (option == 2) {
                    deleteTask(tasks, &numTasks, tasks[i].day, tasks[i].month, tasks[i].year);
                } else
                if (option == 3) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    goBack = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!tasksFound) {
            setConsoleColor(14);
            printf("\x1b[31mNo tasks found for %d %s %d\x1b[0m \n",
                   selectedDate, getMonthName(selectedMonth), selectedYear);
            setConsoleColor(15);
            goBack = 1;
        }
        pressEnter();
    }
}

int editTask(struct task *task, struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks) {
    if (*numTasks == 0) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nNo task available to edit.\n");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        return 0;
    }

    int taskIndex = 1;
    if (!getInteger("Enter the index of the task to edit", "task index", 1, *numTasks, &taskIndex))
        return 0;

    taskIndex--;

    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("\nEditing Task:\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);
    printf("Task Name: %s\n", tasks[taskIndex].name);
    printf("Notes: %s\n", tasks[taskIndex].notes);
    printf("Date: %d %s %d\n", tasks[taskIndex].day, getMonthName(tasks[taskIndex].month), tasks[taskIndex].year);

    int confirmation = 0;
    if (getInteger("\nDo you want to edit this task? (1: Yes, 0: No)", "number", 0, 1, &confirmation))
        return 0;
    if (confirmation
    &&  getInput("Enter new task", tasks[taskIndex].name, sizeof(tasks[taskIndex].name))
    &&  getInput("Enter new notes", tasks[taskIndex].notes, sizeof(tasks[taskIndex].notes))
    &&  getInteger("Enter new day", "day", 1, 31, &tasks[taskIndex].day)
    &&  getInteger("Enter new month", "month", 1, 12, &tasks[taskIndex].month)
    &&  getInteger("Enter new year", "year", 2023, 2033, &tasks[taskIndex].year)) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nTask edited successfully!\n");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        saveTasks(tasks, *numTasks);
        return 1;
    } else {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nEdit cancelled.\n");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        return 0;
    }
}

int deleteTask(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks, int selectedDate, int selectedMonth, int selectedYear) {
    if (*numTasks == 0) {
        printf("\nNo tasks to delete.\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        // What if there is more than one task on the given day?
        int taskIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < *numTasks; i++) {
            if (tasks[i].day == selectedDate && tasks[i].month == selectedMonth && tasks[i].year == selectedYear) {
                taskIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (taskIndex == -1) {
            printf("\nNo task found on the selected date.\n");
            pressEnter();
            return 0;
        } else {
            for (int i = taskIndex; i < *numTasks - 1; i++) {
                tasks[i] = tasks[i + 1];
            }
            (*numTasks)--;
            printf("\nTask deleted successfully!\n");
            saveTasks(tasks, *numTasks);
            pressEnter();
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

int changePassword(void) {
    struct user user;
    int userFound = 0;
    char username[100], pword[100];

    if (!getInput("Enter your username", username, sizeof username)
    ||  !getPassword("Enter your current password", pword, sizeof pword))
        return 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("Users.dat", "rb+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 0;
    }

    while (fread(&user, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(user.username, username) == 0 && strcmp(user.password, pword) == 0) {
            userFound = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!userFound) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\n\nUser is not registered or incorrect password!\n");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        pressEnter();
    } else
    if (getPassword("\nEnter your new password", user.password, sizeof user.password)) {
        // should ask for confirmation and check password strength
        fseek(fp, -sizeof(struct user), SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(&user, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);

        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nPassword changed successfully!\n");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        pressEnter();
    }
    fclose(fp);
    clearConsoleScreen();
    return userFound;
}

int saveTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int numTasks) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("tasks.dat", "wb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file!");
        return 0;
    }
    fwrite(tasks, sizeof(struct task), numTasks, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}

int findUser(const char *username, const char *pword) {
    struct user user;
    int userFound = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("Users.dat", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening Users.dat");
        return 0;
    }
    while (fread(&user, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(user.username, username) == 0 && strcmp(user.password, pword) == 0) {
            userFound = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return userFound;
}

void signIn(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks) {
    char username[100], pword[100];
    int taskIndex = 0;

    if (!getInput("Enter your username", username, sizeof username)
    ||  !getPassword("Enter your password", pword, sizeof pword))
        return;

    if (!findUser(username, pword)) {
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\nUser is not registered or incorrect password!\n");
        setConsoleColor(15);
        pressEnter();
        clearConsoleScreen();
        return;
    }

    for (;;) {
        clearConsoleScreen();
        setConsoleColor(14);
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t-----What do you want to do today?-----\n");
        printf("1. See your schedule and calendar\n");
        printf("2. Add your task and notes\n");
        printf("3. Log out\n");
        setConsoleColor(15);

        int choice = 3;
        getInteger("Enter your choice", "choice", 1, 3, &choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
        {
            int targetMonth, targetYear;
            if (getInteger("Enter the month", "month", 1, 12, &targetMonth)
            &&  getInteger("Enter the year", "year", 2023, 2033, &targetYear)) {
                displayCalendar(targetMonth, targetYear, tasks, *numTasks, 0, 0, 0);
                if (taskIndex < *numTasks)
                    displayTasks(tasks, *numTasks, tasks[taskIndex].day, tasks[taskIndex].month, tasks[taskIndex].year);
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            int newTask = *numTasks;
            if (newTask >= MAX_TASKS) {
                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("No task available\n");
                setConsoleColor(15);
                break;
            }
            if (getInput("Enter task name", tasks[newTask].name, sizeof(tasks[newTask].name))
            &&  getInput("Enter the notes", tasks[newTask].notes, sizeof(tasks[newTask].notes))
            &&  getInteger("Enter the day", "day", 1, 31, &tasks[newTask].day)
            &&  getInteger("Enter the month", "month", 1, 12, &tasks[newTask].month)
            &&  getInteger("Enter the year", "year", 2023, 2033, &tasks[newTask].year)) {
                (*numTasks)++;
                saveTasks(tasks, *numTasks);

                setConsoleColor(14);
                printf("\nTask added successfully!\n");
                setConsoleColor(15);

                pressEnter();
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:
            printf("\nLogging out...\n");
            pressEnter();
            clearConsoleScreen();
            return;
        }
    }
}

int loadTasks(struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS], int *numTasks) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("tasks.dat", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        *numTasks = 0;
        return -1;
    }
    *numTasks = fread(tasks, sizeof(struct task), MAX_TASKS, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return *numTasks;
}

int main(void) {
    int numTasks = 0;
    struct task tasks[MAX_TASKS];

    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    loadTasks(tasks, &numTasks);

    for (;;) {
        int choice = 4;
        displayMenu();
        getInteger("Enter your choice", "choice", 1, 4, &choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            signIn(tasks, &numTasks);
            continue;
        case 2:
            createAccount();
            continue;
        case 3:
            changePassword();
            continue;
        case 4:
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    clearConsoleScreen();
    setConsoleColor(14);
    printf("Exiting the application. Goodbye!\n");
    setConsoleColor(15);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ah okay i'm sorry i didn't know there are some conditions for the questions. Thank you for telling me